# Is there a way to get typeof Func<T, bool>?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

**Short version :**

We can get the typeof `Func<T,T>` using:

```
typeof(Func<,>)
```

but what if I want to get the type of `Func<T, bool>`, what should I use, or is it possible to do? Clearly this doesn't compile :

```
typeof(Func<, bool>)
```

---

**Long version :**

Consider the following scenario, I have two similar method and I want to get the second one (`Func<T, int>`) using Reflection:

```
public void Foo<T>(Func<T, bool> func) { }

public void Foo<T>(Func<T, int> func) { }
```

I'm trying this:

```
 var methodFoo = typeof (Program)
            .GetMethods()
            .FirstOrDefault(m => m.Name == "Foo" &&
                        m.GetParameters()[0]
                        .ParameterType
                        .GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof (Func<,>));
```

But since the generic type definition of `Func<T, bool>` and `Func<T, int>` are equal it gives me the first method. To fix this I can do the following:

```
var methodFoo = typeof (Program)
            .GetMethods()
            .FirstOrDefault(m => m.Name == "Foo" &&
                        m.GetParameters()[0]
                        .ParameterType
                        .GetGenericArguments()[1] == typeof(int));
```

Then I get the correct method but I do not like this way. And it seems like a overhead for more complex situations. What I want to do is get the type of `Func<T,bool>` like in my failed attempt above, then instead of using Linq I can use [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5fed8f59(v=vs.110).aspx) of `GetMethod` and do something like the following:

```
var methodFoo = typeof (Program)
            .GetMethod("Foo", 
            BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance,
            null, 
            new[] {typeof (Func<, bool>)}, // ERROR typeof(Func<,>) doesn't work either
            null);
```

Note: Ofcourse `Func<T,T>` is just an example, question is not specific to any type.

Comment: +1 Good question! Where is Jon Skeet when we need him? haha

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot build a `System.Type` object for a partially bound generic type. The way that you do it (i.e. with `GetGenericArguments()[1] == typeof(int)`) is the proper way of doing it.

If you need to re-use this in multiple places, you could build a helper extension method that takes a generic type definition and an array of `System.Type` objects, and returns `true` if there is a match:

```
static bool IsGenericInstance(this Type t, Type genTypeDef, params Type[] args) {
    if (!t.IsGenericType) return false;
    if (t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() != genTypeDef) return false;
    var typeArgs = t.GetGenericArguments();
    if (typeArgs.Length != args.Length) return false;
    // Go through the arguments passed in, interpret nulls as "any type"
    for (int i = 0 ; i != args.Length ; i++) {
        if (args[i] == null) continue;
        if (args[i] != typeArgs[i]) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Now you can rewrite your code like this:

```
var methodFoo = typeof (Program)
    .GetMethods()
    .FirstOrDefault(m => m.Name == "Foo" &&
        m.GetParameters()[0]
            .ParameterType
            .IsGenericInstance(typeof(Func<,>), null, typeof(bool))
    );
```

> if I use `methodFoo.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType`, I'm getting the type of `Func<T, int>` so it is definitely being constructed somewhere

The type `T` above is the generic type parameter of your generic method `Foo`. Since it is not "any type", you could construct this type if you wish:

```
var typeT = methodFoo.GetGenericArguments()[0];
var funcTbool = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(typeT, typeof(bool));
```

The catch is that `typeT` is bound to the specific generic method, making the `funcTbool` type not suitable for searching across multiple independent generic methods.

If `T` were a type argument of the class to which the method belongs, say

```
class FooType<T> {
    public void Foo(Func<T, bool> func) { }
    public void Foo(Func<T, int> func) { }
}
```

you would be able to construct a `funcTbool` based on `FooType<>`'s generic type parameter, and search for it in the signatures of the different `Foo(...)` methods.

Comment: if I use `methodFoo.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType`, I'm getting the type of `Func<T, int>` so it is definitely being constructed somewhere.. I thought may be it is possible to get it directly.

Comment: @Selman22 That's a fair observation - take a look at the edit.